# Get Unicode code point for the input character - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, unicode, ios5

I'm trying to translate Visual Basic code to objective C, but I can not find the solution to the VB function AscW, that returns the Unicode code point for the input character.

Any one can help me on it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSString has a method [characterAtIndex:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414645-characteratindex?language=objc) that returns a `unichar`

Comment: You are welcome. If this solved your problem, I would be very grateful if you accepted this as the right answer.

Comment: What the method returns is semantically UTF-16 encoded byte pair, not Unicode code point. It mostly matches, but there're exceptions such as surrogate pairs.